# $1+x^p+x^{2p}+\dotsb+x^{p(p-1)}$ irreducible

Tags: irreducible-polynomials

> Let $p$  be a prime number. Is 
> $$f(x)=1+x^p+x^{2p}+\dotsb+x^{p(p-1)}$$
> an irreducible polynomial over $\Bbb Z$?

Can we use Eisenstein's criterion?

$f(x+1)=1+(x+1)^p+(x+1)^{2p}+\dotsb+(x+1)^{p(p-1)}$

I am stuck. Thanks a lot!

Comment: $t=x^p\iff f(x)=\dfrac{t^p-1}{t-1}$

Answer (score 1):

The constant term of $f(x+1)$ is $p$. So you can use the Eisenstein's criterion for this question.

Comment: coefficients of $x^p, x^{2p}$  ?

Comment: @ziangchen: no, the constant term of the polynomial p(x+1) is 1 + 1 +...  + 1 = p